# XQuery Comparison Expressions in SQL Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, xquery, xquery-sql

I would like to have a table that I can store [XQuery Comparison Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190935.aspx) in, so that I can evaluate them in a query.

I've been doing a bit of R&D into if it is possible, and I'm struggling.

If I put an XQuery expression in a column, then it seems to evaluate differently to if I put the XQuery expression directly into the query. For example, when I run the below query:

```
declare 
  @x xml = ''

create table #condition
(
    condition nvarchar(255)
)

insert into #condition
values
('''1''=''1''')

select 
  condition, 
  @x.query('sql:column("condition")'),
  @x.query('''1''=''1''')
from #condition
```

I would expect this to return:

```
'1'='1', true, true
```

However it actually returns:

```
'1'='1', '1'='1', true
```

Does anybody know how I can evaluate comparison expressions that are stored in a column?

The eventual plan is to be able to use this technique to filter down rows of a table based on XQuery conditions present.  So ultimately I'd want to be able to do this in the where clause of a select statement.

I've put the above example into an [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/3086) encase it is useful.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Unfortunately you can't.

`sql:column("condition")` will be evaluated to a suitable XML primitive data type based on the table column type. In this case the value from `condition` column will always be evaluated as XML `string` type instead of an XQuery statement, as you have figured out from running your sample query. And I can't see anyway of evaluating dynamic XQuery statement, unless you want to construct the entire query dynamically and execute it later on possibly using [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Comment: Hi, the more I look into it, the more I understand why dynamic XQuery statements are impossible.  The only way I think you could fudge it would be to use dynamic sql as you suggest, but I'd rather not use that solution in this case.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  Back to the drawing board on this one...

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

declare 
  @x xml = ''

create table #condition
(
    condition nvarchar(255)
)

insert into #condition
values
('''1''=''1''')
select 
    condition,
    case when col1 like col2 then 'True' else 'False' END col,
    quer
from
(
    select 
      condition, 
      PARSENAME(REPLACE(condition,'=','.'),2) col1, 
      PARSENAME(REPLACE(condition,'=','.'),1) col2 ,
      @x.query('''1''=''1''') as quer
    from #condition
)base

Comment: Hi, this would work for a simple X=Y statement, however it wouldn't work for more complex xquery statements (such as X>Y, (X+Y)<Z, etc)...  Thanks for the suggestion though!